# .Net Core Web App missing some Bootstrap classes at creation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, .net-core, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to follow some tutorials on .Net core web apps.

I started running into issues first when I tried to use glyphicons. They never worked and I got the intellisense warning "Unknown CSS Class 'glyphicon'".

As I got further into the tutorials I would increasingly run into these types of CSS warnings. Input-Group-btn, btn-default, and panels all gave similar warnings and didn't work. But I thought I must have missed a step or something.

But now I'm looking at the default _Layout.cshtm and seeing similar warnings, and understanding that, that's probably why my pages don't look like the examples. Navbar-toggleable-sm is an unknown class.

To be clear, *many* of the classes work. Most, even.

I thought maybe it was just a version issue, but glyphicons and panels don't seem seem like they would be deprecated features.

I'm looking in my bootstrap distribution and it looks like I'm on version 4.3.1.

Why would these classes be missing and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer to this appears to be that many, MANY features have been changed between bootstrap 3 and 4, and Microsoft didn't update their templates. So by default bootstrap 4 is installed, but the pages generated use bootstrap 3 classes.

For glyphicon you can use FontAwesome.

Panels, thumbnails, and wells have all been replaced with cards.

[More information can be found here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)